# Windows Command line batch script to get data from different source files

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, hardlink

I'm trying to do a script which would take data from multiple source files. I want to create Hardlinks from filename1 refering to filename2. It means the script will take 1st row (file path) from filename1   and make a hardlink with name and path from 1st row from filename2, then 2nd row from filename1 to 2nd row from filename2 etc. Is it possible to do it?
Thank you in advance for any help.

I was trying 2 for /f commands, but it doesn't do what I need.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do for /F "tokens=*" %%B in (myfile2.txt) do (
mklink /h %%A %%B
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a method to read from two files in parallel. This is possible by using two methods at the same time (`<file1 set /p` and `for /f ... in (file2)`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

<myfile2.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (myfile1.txt) do (
    set /p b=
    echo %%a - !b!
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. This works great:). I'm just wondering, if myfile3 could be included in case I need some custom switches to the command.s So the same thing, just apply switches (/h, /d etc.) from myfile3 from respective line?

Comment: yep: [cross-site reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14523100/2152082)